# smart theming - load images and css from child location

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, themes

I'm thinking of a smart theme solution for my project. And the idea is this: have a separate folder called themes and inside a folder called global for my images and style sheets. There would be more folders inside called, let's say, black and white.

File structure (directories marked pipe |, files asterisk *):

```
| global
  | css
    * style.css
    * global.css
  | img
    * logo.png
    * background.png
| white
  | css
    * style.css
  | img
    * logo.png
| black
  | css
    * style.css
  | img
    * background.png
```

Now what I would like to achieve is a sort of overload for static content. Let's say there's a white theme selected. Then all the requests for the 4 files would look like this:

```
./white/css/global.css
./white/css/style.css
./white/img/logo.png
./white/img/background.png
```

There would have to be a set of rules to make the actual requests to

```
./global/css/global.css
./white/css/style.css
./white/img/logo.png
./global/img/background.png
```

Because global.css and background.png do not exist in the requested theme.

I think the best way to make it as transparent as possible is to define those rules in htaccess. Unfortunately, I am not such a htaccess guru, so I'm turning to stackoverflow. I'm basically getting stuck with the if conditions and checking whether the actual requested file exists.

Any help and advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All that was needed is to put .htaccess in the folder called themes with these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (/.*) global$1
```